# Parsing JSON converted XML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xml, soap

I am building an API that send a SOAP request to a web service in express, i used [easy-soap-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-soap-request) to send SOAP request and naturally i got an XML response, then i used [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) to convert the response. This was the response:

```
 {
  "s:Envelope": {
    "$": {
      "xmlns:s": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    },
    "s:Body": [
      {
        "SmartSearchIndividualResponse": [
          {
            "$": {
              "xmlns": "some-url"
            },
            "SmartSearchIndividualResult": [
              {
                "$": {
                  "xmlns:a": "yet-another-url",
                  "xmlns:i": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                },
                "a:IndividualRecords": [
                  {
                    "a:SearchIndividualRecord": [
                      {
                        "a:Address": [
                          "person-address"
                        ],
                        "a:DateOfBirth": [
                          "person-DOB"
                        ],
                        "a:FullName": [
                          "person-full-name"
                        ],
                        "a:IDNumber": [
                          "person-ID-number"
                        ],
                        "a:CompID": [
                          "company-ID"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

is there anyway to extract some data like address or full name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very bad JSON structure

```js
const data = 
      { 's:Envelope': 
        { '$': { 'xmlns:s': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'} 
        , 's:Body': 
          [ { 'SmartSearchIndividualResponse': 
              [ { '$': { 'xmlns': 'some-url'} 
                , 'SmartSearchIndividualResult': 
                  [ { '$': 
                      { 'xmlns:a': 'yet-another-url'
                      , 'xmlns:i': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
                      } 
                    , 'a:IndividualRecords': 
                      [ { 'a:SearchIndividualRecord': 
                          [ { 'a:Address':     [ 'person-address'   ] 
                            , 'a:DateOfBirth': [ 'person-DOB'       ] 
                            , 'a:FullName':    [ 'person-full-name' ] 
                            , 'a:IDNumber':    [ 'person-ID-number' ] 
                            , 'a:CompID':      [ 'company-ID'       ] 
      } ] } ] } ] } ] } ] } } 


let individualRecs = data['s:Envelope']['s:Body'][0]
                        .SmartSearchIndividualResponse[0]
                        .SmartSearchIndividualResult[0]
                        ['a:IndividualRecords'][0]
                        ['a:SearchIndividualRecord'][0]
 

console.log( individualRecs['a:Address'][0] )
console.log( individualRecs['a:FullName'][0] )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank You, this actually worked. This is my first time building an API with SOAP request, and i'm not familiar with XML so this is a big help!

Comment: @AnandaDharma this question is not about XML, it is about javascript object, and a also about JSON...